# Setting up Raspberry Pi to share an ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet, setup

At my college in order to play a gaming console on the internet you have to have an ethernet cable go into your computer then back out and into the console.

The documentation for setting this up on Windows can be found here:
http://technology.pitt.edu/support/connecting-your-gaming-console-to-pittnet-with-windows

Does anyone know if this would be doable with a Raspberry pi and a usb to ethernet adapter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at least the internet sharing part of it -- it's not clear there why you can't just plug the console straight into the router (so beware you might not be able to use a Pi in place of a windows box for other reasons).  There's [a list here of "known working" adapters](http://RPi%20USB%20Ethernet%20adapters) for the Pi.  The issue is probably really the linux driver (on A/B models it may also be power, which should be fine on +/2 models), so if you find something and aren't sure that's what you should check into.

Comment: While Goldilocks has the correct asnwer to your question, I do suggest going out and buying a switch or router for about 10 $/€/£ and make your life easier.